# changes made by TypeScript Property Decorators don't show in log

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

If I run below code to modify the `destination` property:

```
const changeDestination = (value: string) => (target: Object, propertyKey: string) => {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, { value })
}

class Rocket {
    @changeDestination('Mars')
    destination = 'Moon'
}

const rocket = new Rocket()
console.log(rocket.destination) // -> Mars
console.log(rocket) // -> Rocket {}
```

Why does the `destination` property not show on 2nd log, when the 1st log confirms, it is actually there? Like:

```
Rocket { destination: 'Mars' }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The decorator function is called on direct property access and not on class instantiation.
Result: the property is undefined after instantiation.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question by providing initial value to `destination`, and logging the object after the property. I still get similar result.

Comment: You are right. I fiddled a bit on stackblitz and read the TS documentation for property decorator but could not find a hint. Even checked this post (the result that you observed was the same) https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-typescript-property-decorators  it seems that this kind of augmentation is maybe not covered by the logger?!